# Data Streaming with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, data-warehouse

I'm designing an ELT system for a data warehouse and was wondering what is the most effective while still (in some sense) safe way of extracting the data from the source database.

I need to read a couple of tables from the source database, organize it into POCO objects that I can work with effectively. These roughly correspond to the dimensions of my cube. To get the facts into my cube, I need to bulk load huge amounts of data from other tables, make some (non-trivial) transformations on them, and write them into a table in the target database.

Although in principle I would only benefit from a small subset of O/RM features, I'm anyway wondering whether using Entity Framework could be an option. Therefore, my question is whether EF (in its newest version) can handle streaming data. What I mean by that is that I keep some kind of a DataReader open, load a couple of POCOs, make transformation on them, write the results into the second database, dispose them all as soon as I can (I cannot keep them all in memory cause it would blow up) and continue reading until I'm done.

I obviously don't need any change management for these objects and I want to keep them (at least the second category with facts) alive only for a short period of time and dispose them while still in the same transaction. Disposing means for me that not only I get rid of POCOs, but that EF will not keep any infrastructure and not waste even a single byte of memory on any of those objects anymore.

The advantages that I see in using O/RM is that it could simplify querying and transformation to some extent, but I'm not willing to sacrifice too much performance and I'm limited by the overall memory amount that I can consume. Does it make sense to go for EF or should I better stay by plain old ADO.NET DataReader ?

Comment: This is not case for ORM at all. You should use some other technology like SQL Server Integration Services.

Comment: I was thinking about that but unfortunately the transformations of the data are fairly non-trivial so I'm not sure whether SSIS can handle (be extended to handle) things like that

Comment: You can make your own components extending SSIS so probably yes.

Comment: I agree with Ladislav in this case, SSIS as a tool can handle complex transforms as part of an ETL solution.

Comment: Hey Tomas Vana, I am wondering what you decided to do. I am in the same bind, so i am wondering what i should do..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use BLTOolkit. We so that - very nice. ONLY has the small subset that is good for ETL. Like not remembering which objects it got in a transaction etc.

If you use EF, you are dead. ORMs are NOT for data loads, they are for business objects. A lot of the higher level features (uniquing, etc.) comes with a  HUGE price the moment you move 10 million objects ;)

Comment: BLTOOLKIT has been replaced with this library --> LinqtoDB:
https://linq2db.github.io/